# Rails / RSpec: How to test #initialize method?

Tags: ruby, rspec2

How can I specify `#initialize` behaviour with RSpec? For example here:

**generator.rb**

```
class Generator
  attr_accessor :seed

  def initialize(seed = nil)
    @seed = seed || pick_seed
  end

  def pick_seed
    Time.now.to_i
  end
end
```

**generator_spec.rb**

```
require 'generator'

describe Generator

  it "calls 'pick_seed' method unless seed specified" do
  end

end
```

I'd like to set expectation that `pick_seed` method called from `#initialize` method.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For me, expectations are about designing conversations among collaborators.  So, you have to decide - is `#pick_seed` an internal implementation detail or part of a collaborating role's interface?

If `pick_seed` is an implementation detail, an expectation is the wrong tool for the job.  And, since you have an accessor for seed, you can proceed thusly (notice the one-assertion-per-example):

```
class Generator
  attr_accessor :seed

  def initialize(seed = nil)
    @seed = seed || pick_seed
  end

  def pick_seed
    Time.now.to_i
  end
end

describe Generator do
  context "creating" do 
    context "when a seed is specified" do
      it "uses that seed" do
        seed = 123
        generator = Generator.new(seed)
        generator.seed.should == seed
      end
    end
    context "when a seed is not specified" do
      it "creates its own seed" do
        generator = Generator.new
        generator.seed.should_not be_nil
      end
    end
  end
end
```

OTOH, if picking the seed is part of the "seed picker" role, then mocks are valuable in designing the seed picker, and dependency injection is a standard method of assigning the roles.  You could write something like:

```
class GeneratorWithCollaborator
  attr_accessor :seed

  def initialize(seed = nil, seed_picker = self)
    @seed = seed || seed_picker.pick_seed
  end

  def pick_seed
    Time.now.to_i
  end
end

describe GeneratorWithCollaborator do
  context "creating" do
    context "when a seed is specified" do
      it "uses that seed" do
        seed = 123
        seed_picker = double('seed picker')
        seed_picker.should_not_receive(:pick_seed)
        generator = GeneratorWithCollaborator.new(seed, seed_picker)
        generator.pick_seed
      end
    end

    context "when a seed is not specified" do
      it "delegates to its seed picker" do
        seed_picker = double('seed picker')
        seed_picker.should_receive(:pick_seed)
        generator = GeneratorWithCollaborator.new(nil, seed_picker)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: In first code block, wouldn't `generator.seed.should_not be_nil` work even if seed is same and has not been generated? But even if you test for `generator.seed.should_not == seed` won't this test be depended on random generator not accidentally creating same seed every once in a while?

Comment: I'd probably make `def pick_seed` private too fwiw. Does not seem like something that is meant to be publicly available given the accessory - but I guess that's impossible to know.