# How to test service object methods are called?

Tags: rspec-rails

I'm trying to build some tests for my service objects.

My service file is as follows...

```
class ExampleService

  def initialize(location)
    @location = coordinates(location)
  end

  private

  def coordinates(location)
    Address.locate(location)
  end

end
```

I want to test that the private methods are called by the public methods. This is my code...

```
subject { ExampleService.new("London") }

it "receives location" do
  expect(subject).to receive(:coordinates)
  subject
end
```

But I get this error...

```
expected: 1 time with any arguments
received: 0 times with any arguments
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your first example, your `subject` has already been instantiated/initialized (by being passed to `expect`, invoking `coordinates` in the process) by the time you've set expectations on it, so there is no way for the expectation to receive `:coordinates` to succeed. Also, as an aside, `subject` is memoized, so there won't be an additional instantiation in the line that follows.

If you want to make sure your initialization calls a particular method, you could use the following:

```
describe do
  subject { FoursquareService.new("London") }
  it "receives coordinates" do
    expect_any_instance_of(FoursquareService).to receive(:coordinates)
    subject
  end
end
```

See also [Rails / RSpec: How to test #initialize method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530440/rspec-and-initialize-method)

Comment: I agree with the answer to the SO question that I referenced when it said that, in general, you don't want to be testing whether an object calls a private method of that object, which is what you are trying to do here. In your case, I would think you'd want to instead check that the collaborator methods are being called (e.g.  Geocoder.coordinates). That said, your second test should pass unless `@coordinates` is `nil`, since `subject.popular_shops` does otherwise indeed call `search_options`.

Comment: I see. Thanks Peter :)

Answer (score 5):

### How to test service object methods are called?

Short answer: **Don't test at all**

Long answer: After seen [Sandi Metz advice on testing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URSWYvyc42M), you will be agree, and you will want to test the way she does.

This is the basic idea:

- The public methods of your class (the public API), must be tested
- The private methods don't need be tested

Summary of tests to do:

- The incoming query methods, test the result
- The incoming command methods, test the direct public side effects
- The outgoing command methods, expect to send
- Ignore: send to self, command to self, and queries to others

Taken from the [slides](https://speakerdeck.com/skmetz/magic-tricks-of-testing-railsconf) of the conference.